# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'self'

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe, attributeerror

I'm working with classes and I've got self.variables, which is no problem at all until I want to do this:

I want to subtract values of one df by values of another by index

```
import pandas as pd
.
.
.

for index, row in self.DataFrame4.iterrows():

    self.DataFrame1=pd.self.DataFrame3.subtract(self.DataFrame2, axis='index')
```

The result is:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'self' most likely because of "pd.self"
```

What would be a neat solution to fix that issue?

Comment: have you tried removing `pd.` to make it like all the other `self.DataFrame#` references?

Comment: `self.DataFrame1 = self.DataFrame3.subtract(self.DataFrame2, axis='index')` ?

Comment: hey Joel, thanks for the fast response. The error disappeared but the two DataFrames I want to subtract from one another merged somehow (all values are NaN) ... but this should be another issue.